# UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode: how to get/set the hours and minutes via code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

How to get/set the hours and minutes via code from a UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode?

The situation:

- I have an interface in that a user selects just hours and minutes. Then, he saves the information (so, I have to get the hours and minutes from UIDatePicker via code to save in a DB).
- When the user is editing the information saved previously, I want to start the interface with the saved hours/minutes (so, I have to set the UIDatePicker hours and minutes via code with values from DB).

How do I do that with the UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to use the `countDownDuration` property in `UIDatePicker` when the date picker mode is set to `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`.

The countdown duration is in seconds, so you can calculate that from a NSDate as follows (to test it just drop it into the `viewDidLoad` of any `UIViewController`):

```
// Create a new date with the current time
NSDate *date = [NSDate new];
// Split up the date components
NSDateComponents *time = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                            components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit 
                            fromDate:date];
NSInteger seconds = ([time hour] * 60 * 60) + ([time minute] * 60);

UIDatePicker *picker = [UIDatePicker new];
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];
[picker setCountDownDuration:seconds];
[[self view] addSubview:picker];
```

So if the current time is 17:28, the `UIDatePicker` will show "17 hours 28 mins". Simly replace the NSDate with the one you get from the DB and you should be sorted :)