# Change width of components in UIDatePickerModeTime

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker, uidatepickermodetime

Ok so currently in the app I'm working on, I'm using (read: hacking) a `UIDatePicker` with the mode set to `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` to allow users to enter the amount of time they waited. The issue with this is that you can't limit the maximum value (I want it to be 5 hours), as `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` ignores the `maximumDate` and `minimumDate` properties.

So I tried changing the mode to `UIDatePickerModeTime`, which does allow me to set limits. The problem now, is that `UIDatePickerModeTime` doesn't seem to call `widthForComponent:` or `titleForRow:` and the components are really thin and don't have titles.

Previously, they looked really nice, but the limits were not adjustable. How can I change the width of these components? I added screenshots so you can see what I mean (pardon the french in the pics, I was working in the French localization of the app).

This is my first post on SO, after using it ALL the time so if I forgot anything, let me know. I would post the code, but I don't think I'm allowed to (company rules), and it's all convoluted anyways.

This is with the mode set to `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` (aka how I *want* it to **look**):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVukq.png

And this is how it looks with the mode set to `UIDatePickerModeTime` (aka the one that has more functionality, but doesn't look as good):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG581.png

Alternatively, if anyone has a way for me to place an upper limit on the `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` one **and** also enable "0 hours 0 minutes" in that mode (currently, it disables this option since its designed to be a count down timer), please let me know!

Thanks!

PS: I'm using iOS SDK 6.0 and ARC with a deployment target of iOS 5.0+

PPS: "Spam Prevention" wouldn't let me post images since I have no rep. So i left the imgur links

EDIT: here's the code i have in setting the width of the components. I have other custom `UIPicker`s in my app with data sources and all that stuff, but I'd rather not make another custom UIPicker just for something that should be so simple.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if(component == 0){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hours"];
    }else if (component == 1){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minutes"];
    }

}


- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return 160.0f;

}
```

Comment: You cannot customize UIDatePicker in anyway. If you want a customized look then use UIPickerView. Otherwise accept UIDatePicker as it looks like.. :-{

Comment: I don't have the solution to increase the width of your UIDatePicker. But you can limit the maximum hours in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer by the following questions and answers. Try these. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2439271/1083859 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8547514/1083859

Comment: @R.A I saw both of those. Unfortunately, neither are what I need. The `countDownDuration` property only lets me pick the initial selected time, not limit the selectable time. If I could enable/disable certain values, the same way the 0 minutes is enabled only if the hour is greater than 0, then my problem would be solved.