# How to set the UIPicker view default value if it in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode

Tags: ios, iphone

UIDatepicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode.The default minute value in picker is set as 1min.now i need to set that 0 min initially how to do this.anybody please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439003/uidatepicker-in-uidatepickermodecountdowntimer-mode-how-to-get-set-the-hours-an

Comment: @crzyonez777 I used this.but ineed to set the initial minutes 0min